# Preventing duplicate values in several combo boxes with the same datasource in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, combobox

I have five combo boxes all populated from a string dictionary that stores the header text from a datagridview.
In my program,
I want a message box to pop up either immediately a duplicate value is selected or when the OK button is pressed. 
 The code below is an if statement that only works when other combo boxes duplicate the selectedvalue in the first combo box.

Is there a shorter way than this long if statement? and I want to be able to validate every other combo box so they won't have a duplicate. P.S I want the pop up to keep coming up till a unique value is selected.    cbosort1,2,3..are the combo boxes names respectively.

```
if (cboSort1.SelectedValue == cboSort2.SelectedValue || cboSort1.SelectedValue == cboSort3.SelectedValue || cboSort1.SelectedValue == cboSort4.SelectedValue || cboSort1.SelectedValue == cboSort5.SelectedValue)
{
  MessageBox.Show("you cannot choose a duplicate column", "duplicate error");
return;
}
```

Comment: you can add all values in a list, and foreach adding check if item is already in the list

Comment: If you want to be clever you could filter the list(s) incrementally after each pick so that they cant pick a dupe...*and* get rid of the annoying MessageBox as well

Comment: Can you please expain with some code example? thanks @Plutonix

Comment: Nothing to explain: whatever they pick in CBO1, remove it from the DS for the others.  Repeat for 2-4.  It is generally better to make it hard for the user to fail than to punish them afterwards with a modal dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var comboboxes = new[] { cboSort1, cboSort2, ...... };
bool dup = comboboxes.GroupBy(c => (string)c.SelectedValue).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

OR

```
bool dup = comboboxes.GroupBy(c => (string)c.SelectedValue).Count() < comboboxes.Length;
```

Comment: Can you please explain? It is not very clear to me. And where do  I put the error message? Thanks.

Comment: If `dup` is true that means you have duplicate.

Comment: I have done that but it even if I choose a different value, it still takes it as a duplicate.

Comment: I guess, `SelectedValue` is null for some comboboxes. You can use this to see the distinct values  `var values = comboboxes.GroupBy(c => (string)c.SelectedValue).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList()`

Comment: Yes some have null values, so how do I go about it using the distinct values code as shown  in your example? @EZI

Comment: @Jaysparkx Come on, you can do it yourself. Just add a *where*. `comboboxes.Where(c=>c.SelectedValue!=null).GroupBy.......`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really should know it. First time doing it your way and I appreciate your timely response. @EZI

Answer (score 0):

You can first detect the dupe values and then check if your cb1-5 is it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO
{
    public class ComboBox { public string SelectedValue; }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cboSort1 = new ComboBox { SelectedValue = "not a dupe" };
            var cboSort2 = new ComboBox { SelectedValue = "also not a dupe" };
            var cboSort3 = new ComboBox { SelectedValue = "this is a dupe" };
            var cboSort4 = new ComboBox { SelectedValue = "no dupe here" };
            var cboSort5 = new ComboBox { SelectedValue = "this is a dupe" };

            var boxes = new[] { cboSort1, cboSort2, cboSort3, cboSort4, cboSort5 };

            var dupes = boxes
                .GroupBy(cb => cb.SelectedValue)       # groups by the value
                .Where(grp => grp.ToList().Count > 1)  # this value has more then 1 
                .Select(grp => grp.Key);               # just select the SelectedValue

            // now you just check if your CB has this selectedValue:
            if (dupes.Any(d => d == cboSort1.SelectedValue))
                Console.WriteLine("CB1 is a dupe");
            if (dupes.Any(d => d == cboSort2.SelectedValue))
                Console.WriteLine("CB2 is a dupe");
            if (dupes.Any(d => d == cboSort3.SelectedValue))
                Console.WriteLine("CB3 is a dupe");
            if (dupes.Any(d => d == cboSort4.SelectedValue))
                Console.WriteLine("CB4 is a dupe");
            if (dupes.Any(d => d == cboSort5.SelectedValue))
                Console.WriteLine("CB5 is a dupe");        
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
CB3 is a dupe
CB5 is a dupe
```